# How to reset visualization in Movie Player to default when it always crashes on launch?

Tags: 11.04, video-player, totem

I changed the visualization option in a working Movie Player from GOOM to one of the options using libvisual. Now the program automatically freezes whenever it is opened, the preferences menu cannot be reached, and must be Force Quit-ed to close.

I have a feeling it won't work again until the visualization setting is reset. However, "sudo apt-get purge totem" followed by "apt-get install totem" does not work! The viewer window is still black and the program freezes when it is opened.

Additional context:
I initially was looking at the visualization menu because I wanted to install projectm http://projectm.sourceforge.net/ (Milkdrop for Linux) and did "sudo apt-get install libvisual-projectm". However, it did not appear in the menu, and I selected one of the existing included libvisual plugins instead. So the projectm problem is probably an unrelated bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `gconf-editor` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Navigate to `/apps/totem/` and set `visual` to `GOOM: what a GOOM!`:

   [image]

Comment: I think you meant /apps/totem/ . I don't have edit privileges to edit it though. It wouldn't be worth this comment if the ubuntu team hasn't chosen to rename totem to "movie player".

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about gconf-editor. Assumed "purge" would have wiped its configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You should write "configuration editor" in dash (i think it is installed by default) and go to apps -- >totem

there you are given many choices on the right side of the editor . Near the bottom of those choices is the one about Goom named "visual"

rename it to "GOOM: what a GOOM!" which is the default one

Comment: I would have accepted this but I do not have a "dash". Unity doesn't seem to get along with this particular machine's Radeon. Perhaps somehow also related to the libvisual plugin problems.